# Odds of failure over time.

Tags: probability

I was having a discussion with a friend about a video game we're playing an how unlucky I've been with the odds of something occurring and I'm curious to see just how unlucky I've been.  Please excuse my lack of math skills, and correct use of various math terminology.

So here's the scenario:

- An egg has a 1 in 8 chance of becoming a chicken.
- After 50 eggs I'm still unsuccessful in yielding a chicken.

I know each egg has a 1 in 8 chance of becoming a chicken regardless of the success or failure of the previous egg, but what are the odds of failing 50 times in a row based on those odds?

Basically I'm just curious to find out how unlucky I've been thus far and how to calculate how unlucky I'll be should attempt #50, 51, 52... etc, also fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the success rate seems a little row.

As Voldemort mentioned, it definitely shouldn't happen very often.

Think of rolling a dice on a table and (assuming it is equally weighted) you should get a good representation of each of the six sides.

Now, forget that scenario for a moment.

Why? Because in video games numbers are generated pseudo-randomly, i.e. there are no true random numbers. Even then, however, you should get a fairly normalized distribution.

**As an aside: I assume you may be discussing Minecraft. It may be that your particular build (if PC) has some bugs, or some mods you may be running could effect it.*

Comment: LOL... kinda embarrassed to acknowledge that it is in regards to Minecraft :)  I never thought about how odds are generated by the programming could differ from normal odds.  Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: @ramrod: +1 for the minecraft reference :).

Answer (score 0):

The probability is $(\dfrac{1}{8})^{50}$- which is pretty small :).

Comment: This is what I was looking for formula wise.  I feel kinda silly based on how easy it is.  Thanks.